# Write htaccess rewrite rule which should be point to a directory which is not existing in app directory structure

Tags: web-hosting, htaccess, redirects, wordpress

I need to write a rewrite rule so that the url should be point to a directory which is not existing in the application directory. In WordPress all admin process/code in wp-admin, so someone try to login, the url in clients browser will rewrite to `http://example.com/wp-admin/*php`. I need to avoid that, I wish the browser should show the directory ec-admin instead of wp-admin. That is `http://example.com/ec-admin/*php` 
This should achieve only by editing htaccess instead of editing entire code.

Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L] 
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/(.*) /ec-admin/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

But now its showing file not found error, is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: Any web server will throw up a 404 for something that does not exist. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you explain the motivation and thought behind this so that we can better understand??

Comment: For example, wordpress site core folder is wp-admin, so when someone need to login, the site will pointed to wp-admin, the browser will show   that wp-admin in url. I need to avoid that condition, instead of wp-admin i need to show another directory.

Comment: Okay. I will let a WP person answer. They might understand your motivation better based upon experience. I have to run away on business for a few hours.

Comment: Yes bybe like as below 
`http://example.com/blog/admin.php?page=orders` to `http://example.com/admin/admin.php?page=orders`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly with most content management systems its not always as easy to make a simple rewrite in the .htaccess file since the paths are driven from settings in the php and that of your database, this can cause looping effect or a 404 error.

Generally rewriting urls from one from to another while keeping the query string intact will look something like:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*?) ec-admin/$1 [QSA]
```

Notice the `[QSA]` this will keep the query string in tact while renaming admin to ec-admin.

If you find that your website is having unnecessary additional redirect hops, a loop or a 404 error then its likely because WordPress is driving the permalinks as mentioned, thankfully WordPress is extremely popular and there's dozens of [plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/) that will allow you to [**edit permalinks**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=permalink&sort=) in the dashboard or alternatively [**rename the admin folder**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=rename%20admin) for security or other reasons!